# Formatting organizing and filtering data from text files

Tags: parsing, filter, scripting, text-files

I'm looking to go through a bunch of text files in a bunch of folders. I'd like to go through each file line by line and do some basic statistics, like grabbing time stamp and count repeating values. Is there any tool or scripting solution that someone could recommend for doing this?

Another possibility is to have a script/tool that could just parse these files and add them to a database like sqlite or access, for easy filtering.

So far I tried using AIR, but it looks like there might be too much data for it to process, and it hangs, but that could be because of some inefficient filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used QuickMacros for things like this.  It can do just about anyting to a textfile (some illegal in 7 states) as well as connect to databases and perform sql tasks like create and modify tables etc.

I routinely used it to extract data, parse it, and then load it into another database.  Especially useful with Scheduled Tasks.

[Here's the website](http://www.quickmacros.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Perl and CPAN